# Replacing value in csv using pandas isn't working

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm working on a mock back end for an application; practicing OOP.

I'm trying to replace a value in a .csv table and everything seems to be going well until the end where the code simply doesnt change anything. I've tried debugging as shown further down and it shows the values im using are correct

```
    def test2(fname, lname, amount):
        # Open csv
        with open('clients.csv','r') as f:
            read = csv.reader(f)


            # Find index of client
            for index, row in enumerate(read):
                if fname in row[0]:
                    if lname in row[1]:
                        i = index - 1
            
            df = pd.read_csv('clients.csv')
            df.iat[i,6] = amount
```

using `print(df.iloc[i,6])` gives me the value I want to change but using `df.iat[i,6] = amount` does nothing.

(Sorry if this seems messy, I'm new to asking questions on here!)

Comment: Why are you weirdly reading the file twice using different methods?

Comment: Do you want to change value only for the in-memory dataframe, or do you want to change the value in the actual csv file?

Comment: @tripleee Using standard csv read to find row index of client because I knew that previously and I thought I'd use pandas because it seemed easier to do further work on the data XD

Comment: @JohnGordon In the actual file. Say, I want to make another function for whatever reason that re-reads the file, it then shows the appropriate values

Comment: Assigning `df.iat[i,6] = amount` only affects the in-memory dataframe.  It does NOT update the original csv file.

Comment: @JohnGordon OH, thank you! I've also tried df.replace but I assume that also only affects in-memory df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    def test2(fname, lname, amount):
    # Open csv
    with open('clients.csv','r') as f:
        read = csv.reader(f)


        # Find row index of client
        for index, row in enumerate(read):
            if fname in row[0]:
                if lname in row[1]:
                     i = index - 1
                     

        # Update balance
        df = pd.read_csv('clients.csv')
        df.at[i,'Balance'] = amount
        df.to_csv('clients.csv', index=False)
```

is the solution

Comment: While providing a code-only answer may answer the question, it’s recommended to provide an explanation for any additions or edits made. That way, future readers can understand your solution. Please [edit] your answer to add context and/or an explanation to your code.